# Only allow site to be viewed through its proper domain

Tags: apache, url, virtualhost, domain-name

I'm hosting multiple sites on the same Apache server (and IP address) using the standard method of virtual hosts. So I have folders like the following: `/var/www/website1.com/`, `/var/www/website2.com/`, and so on.

I know how to change the DocumentRoot so that requests for a certain domain point to the appropriate directory, but the problem is that the site is also accessible via `123.456.789.000/website1.com/`, where `123.456.789.000` is the server's IP address.

This is especially bad because it's built using Laravel, so the DocumentRoot is actually `/var/www/website1.com/public`, with the main `website1.com` directory being where Laravel stores config files and other private files. It's currently possible to view these files by visiting it at the IP address (thankfully this isn't a critical project).

So how I make sure that a site can only be visited at `website.com` and not `123.456.789.000/website.com/`? I don't necessarily want this to apply globally - I want to be able to choose on a site per site basis whether it should only be accessible through its proper domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a redirect which sends clients to your 'canonical' domain name

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(I don't know anything about 'Laravel', but storing config/private files in web accessible directories sounds really bad)